# How can I set success_mesasge with format() in django generic view?

Tags: django, django-messages

What I want to implement is like this :

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.views.generic import CreateView

from posts.models import Post


class PostNewView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):

    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'image']
    success_message = "{} has been created successfully".format(self.post.title) 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

But it occurs error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't an issue with `format()`, but with trying to reference an attribute that doesn't exist at that point. Attributes at class level are evaluated at import time, but `self.title` only exists at runtime, and only within a method.

Rather than setting the message at that level, you should use the [`get_success_message`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.views.SuccessMessageMixin.get_success_message) method:

```
def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
    return "{} has been created successfully".format(cleaned_data['title'])
```